# Sorting XML results with PHP usort + strcmp? (integers)

Tags: php, strcmp, usort

I am trying to order the results of an AJAX call on my page by comparing the numerical value of one of the fields in the XML object. Basically, it is a product popularity ranking where the higher the number is, the more popular it is.

I almost have it working, except `strcmp` only compares the first digit, so the order goes something like this currently: 1, 12, 15, 19, 2, 21, 24, 3, 34, 36, 39, 5, 52, 56

How can I modify this code so that the numbers are ordered lowest to highest regardless of how many digits there are?

```
$products = array();
foreach($xml->Products as $product) {
    $products[] = $product;
};

// Sort results based on popularity
usort ($products, function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->ProductPopularity, $b->ProductPopularity);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast as integers and do a normal comparison.

```
 usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
      if((int)$a->ProductPopularity==(int)$b->ProductPopularity) return 0;
      return (int)$a->ProductPopularity < (int)$b->ProductPopularity?1:-1;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usort ($products, function($a, $b) {
    return (int)($a->ProductPopularity) - (int)($b->ProductPopularity));
});
```

Or you could swap a and b if you want to reverse the sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr as $i => $row) {
    $arr2[$row['fieldname']] = $row;
}
ksort($arr2);
$arr2 = array_values($arr2);
```